# VBA EXCEL: Can I copy Userform's code to a txt file?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would like to copy the code from a userform using a macro, but I  couldn't find any way to do so, help, please.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is able to be adapted for a userform, but [this may set you on the right track](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Get_the_VBA_Code_String)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/steve-jansen/7589478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will get the text of a userform, code module, or class module. You'll need the Microsoft VBA Extensibility 5.5 reference that @SHK mentioned.

```
Function getCodeText(wb As Workbook, moduleName As String) As String
    Dim myCode As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set myCode = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(moduleName).CodeModule
    getCodeText = myCode.Lines(1, myCode.CountOfLines)
End Function

Sub testCall()
    MsgBox getCodeText(Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm"), "MyUserformName")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need!